# Dumping a 2D register array into a text file

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to dump a 2D array into a text file with dimension [100] width [200] height with each value stored being a 2-bit binary value.
Declared like this:

```
logic [1:0] array_name [99:0][199:0];
```

When I use:

```
$writememb(dump_location, "array_name");
```

the resulting file is created, but it remains empty.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get an error message which points to the problem:

```
Error-[STASKEC_IAFMEMT2] Illegal argument to memory task
tb.sv, 4
tb, "array_name"
  Argument no. 2 to $writememb must be a memory. Argument given is 
  "array_name".
  Please correct the system task call and recompile.
```

You need to delete the quotes around the memory name (`array_name`):

```
module tb;
    logic [1:0] array_name [99:0][199:0];
    string dump_location = "file.txt";
    initial $writememb(dump_location, array_name);
endmodule
```

This creates the file named `file.txt` with the contents of `array_name` (all x's).

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.5 *Writing memory array data to a file*.